# Recurrent Neural Network predicts flat plot, what am I doing wrong

Tags: r, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I have been trying to produce a recurrent neural network in R. It is for a school project. I am at the modeling part part and I keep getting a subscript out bounds error whatever that mean. I have tried using less input variables and changing the test sets. I almost feel like I have an issue with the headers from the data files.

```
rm(list=ls())
# Load libraries
require(rnn)

# Set seed for reproducibility purposes
set.seed(10)

foo <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\farme\\Documents\\UpWork\\Anc Gz\\datav.csv")
bar <- read.csv("https://nofile.io/g/GzVyEeNFHYXTS04Zp5owg22s0K46Ye4yPv3ONq6wr8OVokU6VL4lZOs4HJb1fkTn/data.csv/")
attach(foo)
attach(bar)

X <- as.matrix(foo) 
Y <- matrix(as.numeric(Total))

X <- (X - min(X)) / (max(X) - min(X))
Y <- (Y - min(Y)) / (max(Y) - min(Y))


# Transpose
X <- t(X)
Y <- t(Y)

# Training-testing sets
train <- 1:25
test <- 26:27

# Train model. Keep out the last two sequences.
model <- trainr(Y = Y[train,],
                X = X[train,],
                learningrate = 0.05,
                hidden_dim = 16,
                numepochs = 1500)
```

> Error in X[train, ] : subscript out of bounds

I'm no expert but I would like to get a meaningful output forecast for my project. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you mean one variable? I see all 8 columns.

Comment: The response variable is Yp. But maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: I suggest to read carefully this tutorial: https://www.r-bloggers.com/plain-vanilla-recurrent-neural-networks-in-r-waves-prediction/

Comment: I started over from the blog post @marco. What am I doing wrong? I cannot fit the model.